# Interrupting requests stream when it's X minutes past the hour

Tags: python, while-loop, python-requests

Sorry, noob question here. I'm trying to record an internet radio station from 6 am to 6:30 am, but I can't figure out how to stop the requests stream. Assume this script is scheduled to run at 6 am.

```
import requests
import time

r = requests.get(stream_url, stream=True) #not putting url here but it's defined

with open('6am-630am.mp3', 'wb') as f:
    try:
        while int(time.strftime('%M')) < 30: #do this till it's 30 mins past hour
            for block in r.iter_content(1024):
                f.write(block)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Comment: probably need a `while` statement that checks the current time

Comment: What is the point of `start = time.strftime('%M')`? You never use this variable again...

Comment: Sorry, that was from earlier but I realized that just stores the current minutes past the hour and doesn't update in the while loop. I removed from code example.

Answer (score 1):

Use a context manager:

```
with open('6am-630am.mp3', 'wb') as f:
    try:
        with requests.get(stream_url, stream=True) as r:
            while int(time.strftime('%M')) < 30: #do this till it's 6:30
                for block in r.iter_content(1024):
                    f.write(block)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you Marcus, but it still keeps recording past the cut-off minute for some reason.

Comment: Okay, maybe it's my IDE then. I'll mess around some more. Thanks!